# the same bash script in command line doesn't work when run from a file

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am trying to lean Bash scripting from cygwin. When i manually type the following lines in command prompt, everything works and I see that the number from 1 to 10 are printed on the screen.

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    echo $i;
done
```

However, if I save the script into a file (test.sh) and run "./test.sh", I was shown the following errors

```
./test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/test.sh: line 1: `for i in {1..10}; do
```

This seems very strange to me. i am wondering how come the same script runs fine in command line but not from a file.

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: works fine for me (both cmd-line and in script-file) in bash on ubuntu.

Comment: What text editor are you using to edit the file? It seems possible that your script might be in RTF or other non-plain-text format.

Comment: i was using GVIM in windows. I will try to use :set fileformat=unix to force to save file with unix encoding. Will report back tmr.

Comment: yep, changing the text file to unix encoding works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\r` is a hint. Your file probably has CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings, which the bash interpreter does not handle gracefully. Change your editor settings to use Unix-style (`\n`) line endings, or run `/usr/bin/dos2unix <file>` on your file to reset the line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using unix text editor vi:

open file in vi edit with `vi filename.sh` command;

type in vi `:set ff=unix` command;

save file with `:wq`

It will save the file with unix line endings.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error in Notepad++. From this post, I changed Edit --> EOF Convertion, selected Unix/OSX Format, fixed this issue.