# Android.mk: how to include ffmpeg and Opencv

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg

this is my project situation: I compiled ffmpeg in windows using [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665039/does-anyone-find-this-useful-compiling-ffmpeg-on-windows-with-cywin-and-ndk-r) and I imported the ffmpeg folder (with inside libffmpeg.so file) generated inside my android project (under jni folder). 
In my project I have a jni_part.cpp where I inserted my jni function to operate with opencv.
In my Android.mk I'm using the code below to import opencv and compile the jni_part.cpp

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := ffmpeg-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But what code I should use to import also ffmpeg? I tried to use this code:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpeg-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg-0.8/android/armv7-a/libffmpeg.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ffmpeg-0.8/android/armv7-a/include/
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := ffmpeg-0.8/android/armv7-a/libffmpeg.so
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := true
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

but if from my jni_part.cpp code I try to  include some ffmpeg files/libraries `"#include <libavutil/avstring.h>"` I get this error:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 4 - Mix Java+Native OpenCV ****

C:\android-ndk-r8c\ndk-build.cmd 
Prebuilt       : libffmpeg.so <= jni/ffmpeg-0.8/android/armv7-a/
Install        : libffmpeg.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so
"Compile++ thumb : mixed_sample <= jni_part.cpp
jni/jni_part.cpp:24:32: fatal error: libavutil/avstring.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mixed_sample/jni_part.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Someone could help me please? I need to do this to include ffmpeg codec with the hope to use the function cvCaptureFromAVi...
Thanks in advance