# Why does maven doesn't deploy when run from bash?

Tags: java, bash, maven, cygwin

when I execute maven like this (from cygwin):

```
mvn clean deploy -pl cjr-extract-ws -am -Denv=test -DdeployExtractWS=true
```

it does exactly what it needs to do (build the cjr-extract-ws module with dependencies and deploys it)

But when I have it as single line in a 'deployWS.sh' file and run:

```
./deployWS.sh
```

From cygwin, for some reason it outputs (among a lot of other output) this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ cjr-extract-ws ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact deployment
```

*and* (guess what) skips deployment...

why???

I have

```
<properties>
    <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
</properties>
```

properties in other pom's (like 'parent' for example (and 'business')) but *not* in the cjr-extract-ws' pom.

Comment: Does your script have !#/bin/bash on top? Also, try using using call before the actual mvn command -> call mvn clean deploy -pl cjr-extract-ws -am -Denv=test -DdeployExtractWS=true

Comment: neither the declaration nor the 'call' keyword did the trick; call is even not recognized by cygwin

Comment: This answer solved my issue as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091800/the-same-bash-script-in-command-line-doesnt-work-when-run-from-a-file?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I was finding this issue quite intriguing

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since the question became notable (and hasn't been formally answered) I guessed I could do the honor :)

This question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091800/the-same-bash-script-in-command-line-doesnt-work-when-run-from-a-file?rq=1).

Enjoy!